# SAPUI5 and XML-File as View with “data-sap-ui-resourceroots”?

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have the problem with displying my xml View by doing the Walkthrough OF SAP UI5.

My project structure looks this way:

- 02_Walkthrough

  - resources
  - webapp

    - view

      - App.view.xml
    - index.html

  This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
    content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SAPUI5 Walkthrough</title>
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-preload="async"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "02_Walkthrough": "./"
     }'>
  </script>
  <script>
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {

      sap.ui.xmlview({
        viewName: "02_Walkthrough.view.App"
      }).placeAt("content");

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody"
  id="content">

</body>

</html>
```

But I still get the error that resources could not be loaded.

Could you please provide me any tips?

Comment: are you sure about your folder structure? anyway, just try to fiddle around: "/resources/sap-ui-core.js", "../../resources/sap-ui-core.js" ...

Comment: Tx. for your reply.
You are right, I just corrected the folder structure but the problem I got is not about resource tag.
I get the message: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/XXX/02_Walkthrough/webapp/view/App.view.xml'.
That means that the pfad is correct but it still does not work

Comment: please post the code of your App.view.xml

Comment: <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <Text text="Hello World" />
</mvc:View>

Comment: are you trying to run your application with the windows explorer?

Comment: no, i was trying to open it in chrome, but after your message I also tried edge and it worked...is this because of this " data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" ?

Comment: data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" just means that the latest functionalities of sapui5 are to use. should run in chrome as well. what is your ide?

Comment: I'm just using Atom for this

Comment: use a web server. or just use the web ide or e.g. eclipse with e.g. tomcat

Comment: Yes. I will do this. I hust wanted to try it in the fast way. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To try it in a fast way, you can use this template form openui5.org  -  https://plnkr.co/edit/qBNu4T

Answer (score -1):

Place the App.view.xml file under the folder web app and run the application again.